# POST to Gin fails when it comes from my Android app, but succeeds when from Postman

Tags: android, go, retrofit, go-gin, grpc-go

I'm not quite sure which side is the cause of the issue, but it seems that the request gets  received by `Gin` but doesn't allow the request from the `android` app. The endpoint I'm trying to `POST` to is related to a monolith model which has a type field, and that type field "tells" `Gin` which are the required fields(my workflow is kinda complicated for that part of my system). On the `android` side, I have a counterpart model for that monolith model as I use it for some stuff in the app. Previously, I only need to get the data related to monolith model from the server. Now, I'm implementing the `POST` for it. The `android` copy of the server model looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "thing", indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true)])
data class Thing(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: String,
    @SerializedName("CreatedAt") @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var created_at: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type_id") var type_id: String,
    @ColumnInfo("type") var type: ThingType? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "some_field_1",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var some_field_1: Float = 0.0f,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "some_field_2",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var some_field_2: Float = 0.0f,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "some_field_3",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var some_field_3: Float = 0.0f,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "some_field_4",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var some_field_4: Float = 0.0f,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "some_field_5",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var some_field_5: Float = 0.0f,
    @ColumnInfo(
        name = "parent_id",
        defaultValue = "0"
    ) var parent_id: String
)
```

Then this is a snippet of the monolith server model:

```
type Thing struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID            string    `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;" json:"id"`
    Name          string    `json:"name"`
    TypeId        string    `gorm:"size:40; index; not null" json:"type_id"`
    Type          Type      `gorm:"foreignKey:TypeId; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"type"`
    SomeField1    float32   `json:"some_field_1"`
    SomeField2    float32   `json:"some_field_2"`
    SomeField3    float32   `json:"some_field_3"`
    SomeField4    float32   `json:"some_field_4"`
    SomeField5    float32   `json:"some_field_5"`
    ParentId      float32   `json:"parent_id"`
}
```

Then I `POST` a `Thing` using `Retrofit` like this:

```
@POST("/thing_info")
suspend fun postThingInfo(
    @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
    @Body data: Thing
): Response<Thing>

val thing =
    Thing(
        "",
        "",
        name = binding.txtName.text.toString(),
        type_id = typeId,
        some_field_1 = binding.txtSomeField1.text.toString()
            .toFloat(),
        some_field_2 = binding.txtSomeField2.text.toString()
            .toFloat(),
        some_field_3 = binding.txtSomeField3.text.toString()
            .toFloat(),
        parent_id = parentId,
    )

//then the usual Retrofit boilerplate
```

With those code, I only see that the request gets a 201 but no error even though I return something for every error object that appears in the process.

Here's the golang code btw:

```
ginGine.POST("/thing_info", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    errMsg := clnHelpers.ValidateAccessToken(ctx.GetHeader("access_token"))

    if errMsg != "" {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": errMsg,
        })
        return
    }

    var thing_info models.Thing

    err := ctx.ShouldBind(&thing_info)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    data := &pb.ThingInfo{
        Name:                        thing_info.Name,
        TypeId:                      thing_info.TypeId,
        //other field association
    }

    res, err := srvClient.service.CreateThingInfo(ctx, &pb.CreateThingInfoRequest{
        ThingInfo: data,
    })

    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "thing_info": res.ThingInfo,
    })
})
```

Comment: I don't know about android, but seems `@POST("/thing")` should be `/thing_info`?

Comment: oh, oops. Don't worry about that, just a mistype. I edit my code before posting here so it doesn't really look exactly like my real code. I'll fix that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this question, and I think it's related to `gorm`. So in my actual android model, I added `created_at` to it as I need it for some sorting on the android side. Because it was a field automatically added by `gorm`, I thought I don't really need to supply a value to it when `POST`ing a `Thing`, I don't even need to pass it on `Postman`. Initially, I was just passing an empty string to it, but it didn't like it. Then I thought having

```
var thing_info models.ThingInfo

err := ctx.ShouldBind(&thing_info)
if err != nil {
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "error": err.Error(),
    })
    return
}
```

in my code would give me the error back like how it used to be for all the other errors I've had so far. But it didn't, somehow that previous error isn't getting returned to me. Then I inserted a good ol'

```
fmt.Printf("thing_info bind err: %v\n", err)
```

inside that if statement, and got an error finally(the irony of being happy to find an error). It seems like, again, even though `created_at` was a `gorm` added field, it was trying to convert the empty string I was passing from the android app to a date and time. After some testing, it seems like passing a string that looks like `2023-08-07T4:46:00Z` is acceptable, and fortunately, `gorm` seems to disregard that value and is putting the actual creation date-time of the record.